# What is "{method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects}" at Cprofile result? How can I reduce its time consumption?

Tags: python

This is the profiling result of my python code.

As you can see below, method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects takes too much time ( 17.265 as tottime )

What is it? And is there any way to reduce its time?

When is it called?

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.402    0.402   37.668   37.668 c:\Users\user\Google ����̺�\Business\Project\Jessica Project\jessica-1\simulation\simulatorW.py:239(backtestWithArgumentsList)
        1    0.173    0.173   26.762   26.762 c:\Users\user\Google ����̺�\Business\Project\Jessica Project\jessica-1\simulation\simulatorW.py:110(getPrices)
        1    0.000    0.000   26.588   26.588 c:\Users\user\Google ����̺�\Business\Project\Jessica Project\jessica-1\dto\__init__.py:5(__init__)
        1    1.734    1.734   25.380   25.380 c:\Users\user\Google ����̺�\Business\Project\Jessica Project\jessica-1\dto\__init__.py:21(priceInfoListToDeque)
   815679    2.204    0.000   23.473    0.000 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py:1152(next)
       13    0.021    0.002   20.631    1.587 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py:1039(_refresh)
       12    0.008    0.001   20.609    1.717 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py:937(__send_message)
       12    0.000    0.000   20.601    1.717 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py:1306(_run_operation_with_response)
       12    0.000    0.000   20.601    1.717 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py:1437(_retryable_read)
       12    0.000    0.000   20.597    1.716 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py:1334(_cmd)
       12    0.001    0.000   20.597    1.716 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py:70(run_operation_with_response)
       18    0.001    0.000   17.386    0.966 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py:192(receive_message)
       12    0.013    0.001   17.379    1.448 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py:637(receive_message)
       36    0.066    0.002   17.331    0.481 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py:249(_receive_data_on_socket)
    19984   17.265    0.001   17.265    0.001 {method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects}
        1    2.499    2.499    6.522    6.522 c:\Users\user\Google ����̺�\Business\Project\Jessica Project\jessica-1\simulation\simulatorW.py:138(filterIndicesWithTimeCondition)
```

Comment: Can you share a functional example of your code?

Comment: please share an example of your code

Comment: Reduce calls 19984

Answer (score 1):

It's a low level [networking call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv_into). This is the time spent reading whatever you are loading. Take a look at its [callers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.print_callers).

```
p.print_callers("{method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects}")
```

Keep going up the callers tree picking the ones that have longer times. Remember that the restriction is a ***regexp***. Use escapes when necessary:

```
p.sort_stats("tottime").print_callers("api.py:104\(post\)")
```

The top 4 lines are more interesting than the *recv_into* one. If you go up the caller tree, you're likely to end up in one of those. There could be many ways to optimize those, since no details are provided. Cacheing, compressing, getting only what you need, and otherwise reducing network footprint.